# NetBeans 7.4 Internationalization

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, netbeans, internationalization

I'm using [MKyiong's good guide](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/) on creating a simple internationalization file with JSF 2 and NetBeans 7.4 however the file is ignored and no message is printed.

To summarize I created a directory resources under TestApplication/src/java and a welcome.properties file with content

```
welcome.jsf = Happy learning JSF 2.0
```

Inside a index.xhtml file I insert

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <h3>
            <title>#{msg['welcome.jsf']}</title>
    </h3>
    </h:head>
    ...
```

and inside TestApplication/web/WEB-INF I created a faces-config.xml with content

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>welcome</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Server correctly starts and log is:

```
INFO:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
INFO:   file:/var/www/sample_projects/TestApplication/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_TestApplicationPU login successful
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB BookShopResource: [java:global/TestApplication/BookShopResource, java:global/TestApplication/BookShopResource!rest.BookShopResource]
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB BookShopEJB: [java:global/TestApplication/BookShopEJB, java:global/TestApplication/BookShopEJB!ejb.BookShopEJB]
INFO:   Registering the Jersey servlet application, named rest.BookShopResource, at the servlet mapping /webresources/*, with the Application class of the same name.
INFO:   Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) für Kontext '/TestApplication' wird initialisiert.
INFO:   Monitoring jndi:/server/TestApplication/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
INFO:   Loading application [TestApplication] at [/TestApplication]
INFO:   TestApplication wurde erfolgreich bereitgestellt in 1.207 Millisekunden.
```

Did anything change with NetBeans 7.4 positioning of .properties file? Anything I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created a resources directory under `TestApplication/src/java` and placed your `welcome.properties` file in it, then the path to your file would be:

`TestApplication/src/java/resources/welcome.properties`

and therefore the proper base-name in your `faces-config.xml` would be resources.welcome

```
<base-name>resources.welcome</base-name>
```

Comment: Hi I have the problem the link Ctrl+leftClick not go to declaration  from JSF page, "#{bundle.system}" , that is my unique problem.